# Cause and fix for pop up dialog when using Gnome Music in Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, software-installation

I wanted to try Gnome's music app (gnome-music). After I got it to [recognize my music](https://askubuntu.com/q/551745/40581), I'm facing the [same issue as Saurav on Superuser](https://superuser.com/q/1039200/252532) when trying to run it in inside a Unity session:

> I recently installed [Gnome music](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Music) on a Ubuntu <s>14.04</s> 16.04 system  with Unity desktop. However, there is a peculiar issue. Every time I play a song several windows pop up (six same windows for each song). So when the entire song list is played I have several pop-up windows open and I have to manually close them. Is there a setting which can help resolve this situation? Is it particular to Unity desktop?
>
> See attached pic.
> [image: Gnome music pop-up window]

I went a bit further as stated in my comment to Saurav's question:

> I can confirm this on a few installs of 16.04. To test I used a 16.04 VM installed ubuntu-gnome-desktop logged into the gnome session and gnome-music worked as intended. Back in the unity session I got the pop in the screenshot (and the unity desktop has gnome elements all over the place and looks broken).

**Questions:**

- Can anyone shine some light on why this happens in Unity while it works fine in Gnome on the same installation?
- Can this be fixed? How? (As stated in my comment, the Unity desktop looks broken when installing Gnome desktop.)

Comment: I'd really like to know how to fix this too. It's very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Gnome Music works in the new Ubuntu session of 17.10, so the obvious answer for now is to abandon Unity and jump to the new desktop.